# What is the Genesis key's power after activation?

Tags: protocol, genesis

If somebody had the activator/genesis private key for mainnet
(corresponding to `edpkvVCdQtDJHPnkmfRZuuHWKzFetH9N9nGP8F7zkwM2BJpjbvAU1N`
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_000_Ps9mPmXa/lib_protocol/data.ml#L101 )

could they do any damage? anything at all? if yes what?

Answer (score 2):

It's a convenient way to load and parametrize a protocol, you can specify any key in the previous block to achieve that. After you've reached the no fork point, your shell will refuse to reorganize and the key becomes pointless.